# Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is uint256)

Tags: solidity, foundry

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

error TransferFailed();
 
contract StakeContract{

    mapping(address => uint256) public s_balances;

    function stake(uint256 amount, address token) external returns(bool){
        s_balances[msg.sender][token] += amount;
        bool success =  IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),amount);
        if(!success) revert TransferFailed();
        return success; 
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong? Im following a [youtube guide by Foundry and Patrick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNMfMxGxeag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line: `s_balances[msg.sender][token] += amount;` you are using the mapping incorrectly.
Your mapping can only store `address=>uint256` while you're trying to store `address=>address=>uint256`.

To fix this you can change your mapping to

`mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public s_balances;`

this way you will be able to nest 2 addresses.

Comment: you are a life saver sir. it's hard to be a beginner. thank you so much Y_Y